# Balanced ternary: combinatorial sum

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I was working on the following problem:

> In balanced ternary, how many numbers with $2n$ digits can be expressed using the same number of $+1$ and $-1$ digits, where $n$ is an integer?

After some combinatorial shenanigans, I ended up with this sum as my answer:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{2k}\binom{2n-2k-1}{n-k}$$

But I cannot figure out how to evaluate it. It does not seem to telescope, and WA would not give me a formula.

Does anybody know how to evaluate this sum?

Comment: Can you do $n=2$ for us ? $++--,+-+-,+--+,-++-,-+-+,--++$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we show OPs binomial sum is closely related to *[central trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html)* which do not have a representation in closed form.

> In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write e.g.
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^n](1+z)^k=\binom{n}{k}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}}&\color{blue}{\binom{2n-1}{2k}\binom{2n-2k-1}{n-k}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2k)!(2n-2k-1)!}\cdot\frac{(2n-2k-1)!}{(n-k)!(n-k-1)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(2n-1)!}{(n-k-1)!(n+k)!}\cdot\frac{(n+k)!}{(2k)!(n-k)!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n+k}\binom{n+k}{n-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[z^{n+k}](1+z)^{2n-1}[t^{n-k}](1+t)^{n+k}\tag{2}\\
> &=[t^n](1+t)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(t(1+t)\right)^k[z^k]\frac{(1+z)^{2n-1}}{z^n}\tag{3}\\
> &=[t^n](1+t)^n\frac{(1+t(1+t))^{2n-1}}{(t(1+t))^n}\tag{4}\\
> &=\color{blue}{[t^{2n}](1+t+t^2)^{2n-1}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything, since we are adding zeros only.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, do some rearrangements and use the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z:=t(1+t)$
  \begin{align*}
  A(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k [z^k]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we do some simplifications and use the same rule as in (3).

> We observe the binomial sum (1) represents essentially *[central trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html)*
>   \begin{align*}
> [t^n](1+t+t^2)^n
> \end{align*}
>   for which there is *no closed form* available. In fact we obtain the central trinomial coefficients $[t^{2n}]$ by multiplying (5) with $1+t+t^2$.

**Notes from the experts:**

> D.E. Knuth gives in *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*, Appendix A 7.56 the following representation of a more general expression
>
> \begin{align*}
> [t^n](a+bt+ct^2)^n=[t^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2bt+(b^2-4ac)t^2}}
> \end{align*}
>
> He states that according to the paper *[Hypergeometric Solutions of Linear Recurrences with Polynomial Coeffcients](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~singer/CIMPA/petkovsek_hyper.pdf)* by Marko Petkovšek there exists a closed form (more precisely: a closed form solution as a finite sum of hypergeometric terms) if and only if
>   $$\color{blue}{abc(b^2-4ac)=0}$$
>
> In case of central trinomial coefficients we have $a=b=c=1$. Since then the expression $abc(b^2-4ac)=-3\ne 0$
>   there is no such closed form in particular for the central trinomial coefficients.

Comment: Well-researched answer: (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks, Marko! :-)

Comment: Yes I just read the material from Concrete Math and the Petkovsek paper. I  have the first edition of CM and seeing your link I figure I should probably upgrade to the most recent one. Your reference also applies to the first edition (same numbering).

Comment: I proved the formula you cite by way of enrichment of the page.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Beautiful answer, thank you!

Comment: @Nilknarf: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What  follows  is   more  of  a  comment  on  the   formula  cited  by
@MarkusScheuer, which we  can actually prove. Observe  that when $a=0$
we get

$$[t^n] (a+bt+ct^2)^n = [t^n] t^n (b+ct)^n = b^n$$

so we may suppose that $a\ne 0.$
We start from

$$[t^n] (a+bt+ct^2)^n =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|t|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{t^{n+1}} (a+bt+ct^2)^n 
\; dt.$$

We put

$$w = \frac{t}{a+bt+ct^2} = \frac{1}{a} t + \cdots$$

The series  tells us  that the  circle $|t|=\epsilon$  is mapped  to a
closed circle in  $w$ (one turn) of dominant  radius $\epsilon/a$ plus
lower order fluctuations, which we may deform to a circle $|w|=\gamma$ 
inside said contour, where the map is also analytic in $w.$ This means
that from the two branches

$$t = \frac{1-bw\pm \sqrt{(b^2-4ac)w^2-2bw+1}}{2cw}$$

we must choose the branch

$$t = \frac{1-bw-\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)w^2-2bw+1}}{2cw}
= aw + \cdots$$

(the  other one  has  a  singularity at  the  origin). This  converges
(distance to the nearest singularity)  either with radius $1/2/b$ when
$b^2-4ac=0$ or the distance from the origin to whichever of

$$\frac{-b\pm 2\sqrt{ac}}{4ac-b^2}$$

is  closer. We  take  $\gamma$  so that  $|w|=\gamma$  is inside  this
region. With

$$dt = \frac{(a+bt+ct^2)^2}{a-ct^2} \; dw
= \frac{t^2/w^2}{a-ct^2} \; dw.$$

we thus finally obtain the integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^n} \frac{1}{t} \frac{t^2/w^2}{a-ct^2}
\; dw
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{t/w}{a-ct^2}
\; dw.$$

We claim that

$$\frac{t/w}{a-ct^2} = \frac{1}{1-bw-2ctw}.$$

This is equivalent to

$$t(1-bw-2ctw) = w (a-ct^2)$$

or

$$t = w (a + bt + 2ct^2 - ct^2)
= w \times t / w$$

which holds by inspection. Now

$$\frac{1}{1-bw-2ctw}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)w^2-2bw+1}}$$

and we have shown that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
[t^n] (a+bt+ct^2)^n
= [w^n] \frac{1}{\sqrt{(b^2-4ac)w^2-2bw+1}}.}$$

Comment: Very nice and instructive! (+1)

Comment: Thanks! Did you see the following [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370301/)?

Comment: I was just working on it. Answer added. :-)

Comment: I propose an additional proof at the cited link.

Answer (score 0):

In balanced ternary, all permutations of $n$ each of $+1$ and $-1$ digits are fair game since the leading digit being non-zero is the only requirement. Therefore the count of expressible numbers is the number of ways to choose $n$ positions for the $+1$ or $-1$ digits, which is $\binom{2n}n$ – the central binomial coefficients.